# WPF: databinding to ListView so that listview item's ForeColor reflects bool property value changes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listview

*WPF application, .NET 3.5.*

I have a **ListView** control, to which I bind a collection of business classes.

I'd like to bind the **ForeColor** of items to a bool property of the class (say: MyClass.**Active**), so that the items are displayed in black when active, in light gray when disabled.

I want listview items to change their color on-the-fly, I mean when I'd change **Active** value of one of the instances in my databound collection, its respective listview item would change its color automatically.

What do I need to achieve this? I've found numerous tutorials on WPF databinding on the net, some questions on StackOverflow, but not exactly the same thing, and I don't want to start combining my solution out of everything I can put my hands on, by trial and error.

I know about **INotifyPropertyChanged** (for my business class), **IValueConverter** (but should I need it for a bool??), **DataTrigger** etc.

But which pieces of the puzzle do I really need, what is the simpliest way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do it in a style, and apply that style on your List items. Providing that your object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the property changed event gets raised when IsActive changes, this will change the foreground to Gray if `IsActive = False`

```
<Style x:Key="DisableInactiveTextStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Trigger>
</Style>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DisableInactiveTextStyle}" ... />
```

Comment: I would second this approach, especially given you're not using MVVM.

Comment: Would it work both ways? I mean, when you switch IsActive back to true, foreground color changes back to black? Or should I replace the <Setter Property...> with another <DataTrigger...> analogous to the first one? I'm going to try it in a minute anyway, but just asking :)

Comment: Yes it does work both ways. This is perfectly what I need - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an IValueConverter that takes a bool and returns a color. You can then bind the ForeColor to the MyClass.Active property and use the created converter.

Comment: So I don't need INotifyPropertyChanged for that purpose? It would still catch _myCollection[7].Active = false;_?